# CSS problem in IE 6 and 7

Tags: css, css-float

Kindly visit the following website:

[property.consultfinman.com](http://property.consultfinman.com)

You must have seen the problem, if you are using IE 7 or IE 6. My page is loading fine in FF, IE8, Safari and Google Chrome. But in IE7 floats are not positioned where they are intended to be positioned. and in IE6 everything is shuffled.

Any solution for this problem (keeping in mind that i am not a css guru).

Thanks

Comment: You should validate your code (http://validator.w3.org/ http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/), then stop helping landlords.

Comment: I can't find updated statistics, but I believe that as of February 2011 IE6 is so widely used you could safely ignore it from the beginning. It's one less problem for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of your IE6 bugs are caused by double margin bug which is when you use float and margin in same direction, ex `{ float: left; margin-left: 10px; }`, IE6 magically double the value.
So you need to add `*display: inline;` where you need to use float and margin in same direction.

As for bottom of your design, I have no idea why you specify `background-color: #000000;` at `.featured-content`

This is the reason why you have black background on IE6 and IE7, I can't tell which bug but I'm pretty sure it's something to do with float.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the browser using this

```
<!--[if lt IE 6]>
    <style>
        //your style
    </style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <style>
        //your style
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```

see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

http://www.maratz.com/blog/archives/2005/06/16/essentials-of-css-hacking-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: can you visit the above mentioned website and let me know the solution for the logindiv on the right top corner, which is not even shown in IE7 and in IE6 it goes to next line

Comment: @booota I saw your website the problem is in your Width. Don't use width in %. Set width in pixel or use just Float:left.

Comment: @booota You can also generate the warning on IE 6 using plug-in provided by Google. see [link](http://code.google.com/p/sevenup/#Help_rid_the_world_of_IE6_with_one_line_of_javascript!)